# Jquery menu onhover shows only 1st child

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Just a noob trying to learn, I came out with a problem that when i hover the parent of menu only first child shows up not the rest. Please dont mind the css. Help appreciated.

heres the link to [Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/program_me/s6EXf/2/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s6EXf/3/).

Use

```
$('ul #multimenu').hover(function(){


});
```

Also you are using the same id for all li elements,you should not do that.id's are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Or use this:

```
 $('#multimenu a').hover(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
 },function(){
    $(this).next().hide(); 
 });
```

**working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/s6EXf/5/

changed the HTML to this:

```
<ul id="multimenu">
    <li><a href="#">Example 1</a><div class="submenu"></div></li>         
    <li><a href="#">Example 2</a><div class="submenu"></div></li>    
    <li><a href="#">Example 3</a><div class="submenu"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Example 4</a><div class="submenu"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Example 5</a><div class="submenu"></div></li>
</ul>
```

removed the first child class because that can be done with css pseudo class `:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple controls with same id you can use name instead. So I changed the

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/s6EXf/15/)**

```
   $('li[name=multimenu]').hover(function() {
      $(this).children('.submenu').show();
     }, function() {
         $(this).children('.submenu').hide();
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using multimenu as an **id** in all li's its wrong. Id's can be used one in a page. Id's are unique.

I changed all id to class & its working see below example.

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/s6EXf/6/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the id must be unique, and js gets only the first one. Change id="multimenu" to class="multimenu" then the js code should be:

```
 $('.multimenu').hover(function(){

        $(this).children('.submenu').show();


     },function(){

        $(this).children('.submenu').hide();

     });​
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Example 1</a>
    <div class="submenu">
         <div>aaaa<div>
         <div>bbbb<div> 
         <div>cccc<div>     
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Example 2</a>
    <div class="submenu">
         <div>1111<div>
         <div>2222<div> 
         <div>3333<div>     
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Example 3</a>
    <div class="submenu">
         <div>xxxx<div>
         <div>yyyy<div> 
         <div>zzzz<div>    
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Example 4</a>
    <div class="submenu">
         <div>4444<div>
         <div>5555<div> 
         <div>6666<div>    
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

​

CSS:

```
ul li { 
float:left;
margin-left:1em;    
}
.submenu {
position:absolute; 
display:none;
width:105px;  
height:150px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; 
background:#ccc; 
z-index:123;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
   $(this).children('.submenu').show();
   }, function() {
   $(this).children('.submenu').hide();
});​
```

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/naresh3591/4H5BE/4/